# Titanium iOS - agcalendar monthview won't update view

Tags: iphone, ios, titanium, titanium-modules

After a new event is added... or an event is deleted I have to hit the next month button then go back to the current month for it to update the calendar properly. I got around this by using the `calendarView.selectTodaysDate();`. This seems to work for the most part on added events, however it doesn't work when an event is deleted

this is the module I'm using for the monthView: 
[Module Link](https://github.com/Appgutta/AGCalendar)

I'm thinking at this point maybe I could make the view refresh, but am not 100% sure how Titanium does that.

Any help would be sincerely appreciated!